# how to detect mousereleased on jframe border?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouseevent, border

at the end of resizing my jframe (dragging the border), I need to know when the user releases the mouse on the border, to make specific treatment. I have searched but it appears that all I have found are more complicated / specific cases.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FrameDemo {

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("");
    emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 100));
    frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            System.out.println("componentResized");
            here I am resizing the components inside the contentPane, no interruption, it's ok
        }
    });
    frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("released");
            **here I need to do specific action on a component but it is never fired**
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible option is to use:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit.setDynamicLayout(false)
```

This means the layout of the frame will only be done when the mouse is released, which means the `componentResized()` event is only fired once.

Otherwise you will need to use an undecorated frame and then add back in your own custom Border and resizing code.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Trail: Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing, Using Top-Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) the border is not part of the JFrame.

[How to Make Frames (Main Windows)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html): *"A frame [...] is a window that has decorations such as a border"* ... *"By default, window decorations are supplied by the native window system."*